# What's the difference between v.Type().Elem() & v.Elem().Type()?

Tags: go, reflection

In the following code, both options seem to allocate the same resource

```
func Allocate(v interface{}) error {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if rv.IsNil() {
        return errors.New("Value of v is nil")
    }
    s0 := reflect.New(rv.Type().Elem())
    s1 := reflect.New(rv.Elem().Type())

    return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("What's the diff? %v %v", s0, s1))
}
```

If there's no difference in this specific example, an example illustrating the difference will be great. Also what's the preferable option in this specific case when trying to allocate for an interface.

Edit: reflect.DeepEqual(s0, s1) returns false. I think rv.Elem().Type() has a problem dealing with zero values so maybe rv.Type().Elem() is preferred.

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8HydwIfgP3)

Comment: I think none if `v` is a pointer type.

Comment: I didn't think so either but there must be some difference because reflect.DeepEqual(s0,s1) returns false

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference if `v` is a non-nil pointer type.

```
s := "hello"
rv := reflect.ValueOf(&s)
fmt.Println(rv.Type().Elem() == rv.Elem().Type()) // prints "true"
```

Here are some examples where `rv.Type().Elem()` and `rv.Elem().Type())` are different:

```
// nil pointer
var p *string
rv := reflect.ValueOf(p)
fmt.Println(rv.Type().Elem()) // prints "string"
fmt.Println(rv.Elem().Type()) // panic: call of reflect.Value.Type on zero Value

// interface value
var i interface{} = "hello"
rv := reflect.ValueOf(&i).Elem()
fmt.Println(rv.Type())        // prints "interface {}"
fmt.Println(rv.Elem().Type()) // prints "string"
fmt.Println(rv.Type().Elem()) // panic: Elem of invalid type
```

If `rv.Type().Elem()` is used in `Allocate`, then the nil check can be removed and the function will work with nil pointer values.

The call `reflect.DeepEqual(s0, s1)` returns false because the [ptr fields](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/fd8028dec92166545d080de99021c9c51f05c670/src/reflect/value.go#L42) in the values are different.  `DeepEqual` compares unsafe pointers as simple values, not as pointers. This example might help explain what's going on:

```
v := "hello"
rv := reflect.ValueOf(&v)
s0 := reflect.New(rv.Type().Elem())
s1 := reflect.New(rv.Elem().Type())
s2 := reflect.New(rv.Type().Elem())
s3 := reflect.New(rv.Elem().Type())
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(s0, s1)) // prints "false"
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(s0, s2)) // prints "false"
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(s1, s3)) // prints "false"
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(s2, s3)) // prints "false"
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(s0.Interface(), s1.Interface())) // prints "true"
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(s0.Interface(), s2.Interface())) // prints "true"
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(s1.Interface(), s3.Interface())) // prints "true"
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(s2.Interface(), s3.Interface())) // prints "true"
```

As you can see, the reflect.Value comparisons are all false, even when created using the same sequence of calls.

Comment: Looks like it. As long as rv.Elem().IsValid(), the two are similar.